# Rails 5.2.1: File input being replaced by text inputs - ActiveAdmin nested attributes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, rails-activestorage

### How can I stop my file input field being replaced by my text input fields?

### Versions:

> Rails 5.2.1
>
> ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
>
> rvm 1.29.4

I am using an Active Admin form to create a new object - `product` that can have many `support_docs`. The `support_doc` has two attributes:

1. An Active Storage file attachment
2. filename

The form works fine when I do not include the `support_doc :filename` input - e.g I can attach the file no problem. But when I include the `filename` attribute input, or any other input field, the file input field disappears (not even in the HTML DOM).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a model (let's call it A) that has many other models (B)
2. In A, allow nested attributes for B
3. In the form for creation of A, set file field and filename inputs for B in nested attributes `has_many` section

### Product.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null


class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :support_docs, inverse_of: :product

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :support_docs
end
```

### Support_doc.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: support_docs
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  filename   :string
#  product_id :integer


class SupportDoc < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :doc_file
  belongs_to :product

  validates_presence_of :product
end
```

### products.rb (form in Active Admin resource)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  permit_params :title, support_docs_attributes: [:doc_file, :filename]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.has_many :support_docs do |doc|
        doc.file_field :doc_file, direct_upload: true
        doc.input :filename
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

### Example:

When I do not include the `:filename` input (line 9 in `products.rb`):
[image: without line 9]

And when I do include the `:filename` input:
[image: line 9 included]

As you can see, the file input field is replaced by any input field I include. I've done as much research as I can on this, but I can't find anyone with a similar issue!

Comment: @sawa Sorry, updated my question to include the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed!

The `doc.file_field` was causing the problem. I switched it with `doc.input :doc_file as: :file`. Clearly you must not be able to tie a `file_field` into a nested form with `inputs`!